# AVFoundation: Compression property Quality is not supported for video codec type avc1

Tags: swift, macos, avfoundation

I *think* I'm looking for a way to check if a video settings key is valid, so I can exclude it if it isn't. But I'm more curious why some keys are valid sometimes, inconsistently. Let me explain.

With my macOS app, I'm trying to write a video with compression quality set, like so

```swift
 let videoWriter = AVAssetWriterInput(
            mediaType: .video,
            outputSettings:
                [
                    AVVideoWidthKey: 1000,
                    AVVideoHeightKey: 1000,
                    AVVideoCodecKey: AVVideoCodecType.h264,
                    AVVideoCompressionPropertiesKey: [
                        AVVideoQualityKey: 0.4
                    ]
                ]
        )
```

It works on my M1Max (13.4, 13.5), Intel Mac (12.0.1), but for one (for now?) of my users (on 13.5/Intel, Macbook16,1) this line throws an exception and crashes the app.

This is the output

```
*** -[AVAssetWriterInput initWithMediaType:outputSettings:sourceFormatHint:] 
Compression property Quality is not supported for video codec type avc1
```

### Reproducing sample app

This tiny app reproduces the crash for my user (but still, not for me)
https://github.com/mortenjust/CompressionCrashTest/blob/main/CompressionCrashTest/ContentView.swift

### What I tried

I tried looking into catching objc exceptions (from AV Foundation) with Swift via a wrapper, but it looks like it's a bad idea, and [not recommended by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/handling-cocoa-errors-in-swift).

I also tried changing the codec to `.hevc` and that also crashes, saying that `Quality` is not a supported key.

I tried asking my user to reboot, no effect.

I tried exporting a video with compression quality 0.1 on my Mac to verify that it's a valid key, and the output video was compressed, small file size and visually distorted.

I tried upgrading from 13.4 to 13.5 to match his specs, but it still doesn't crash for me.

I really wish there was a way to validate a video settings dictionary without crashing.

I found  [AVCaptureMovieFileOutput / supportedOutputSettingsKeys(for:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturemoviefileoutput/2968217-supportedoutputsettingskeys) that vaguely resembles what I need, but it's made for recording from a camera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is really strange as it doesn't seem to be documented. You could wrestle with this, but in my experience, you might have more reliable results using a target bitrate with `AVEncoderBitRateKey`.

The bonus here is that it will let you control file sizes even more directly. An 8 second video at 3Mbps is always 3 MB. Also, it should be universally supported (I've never used the quality key for video in years of working on apps that produce quality-sensitive videos intended for network use).

The downside is that the same bitrate will produce different visual quality levels for different resolutions.

*E.g. 1080p@30 video at 8Mbps = no loss in quality according to Google. (in my experience, it's even overkill).
However, 4K video at 8Mbps would likely have a bunch of tearing and visual artifacts between keyframes.*

Try this and see if it works. Make sure to verify your file sizes and perceived quality as QA. At the very least you'll remove a layer of mystery, which can be worth a lot.

Comment: Good points. It's almost like the docs are hinting that compression quality is only for the JPEG codec. To test this hypothesis I tried writing the same video at 100% and 40% and then ffprobe to see if the bit rate changes. And it does; 40% quality is 1000 kb/s, 100% quality is 25841 kb/s. So maybe AV Foundation just tries to be smart about Quality and translates it to bitrates (and more maybe)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for posting this and sharing the findings! I want to add my 2 cents in hope someone more insightful can comment on it.

First of all, the [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avvideoqualitykey) on `AVVideoQualityKey` don't seem to match docs in the headers:

```swift
/// NSNumber (0.0-1.0, JPEG, HEIC and Apple ProRAW only.
/// With HEIC and Apple ProRAW, 1.0 indicates lossless compression)
public let AVVideoQualityKey: String
```

One way you can verify whether a particular codec configuration supports certain properties is by using `VTCopySupportedPropertyDictionaryForEncoder`, see [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/videotoolbox/2887271-vtcopysupportedpropertydictionar).

Some established projects (like HandBrake [here](https://github.com/HandBrake/HandBrake/blob/3226138299e5d3b440b709f8880a3c5347ec8fca/libhb/platform/macosx/vt_common.c#L26) → [here](https://github.com/HandBrake/HandBrake/blob/3226138299e5d3b440b709f8880a3c5347ec8fca/libhb/platform/macosx/vt_common.c#L122) or FFmpeg [here](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/4700925d22c79988688596bda8e862ef3ff39293/libavcodec/videotoolboxenc.c#L1202)) rely on this, and I've been also using it successfully for the year or so.

What I have noticed is that the same codec don't always support the same properties from hardware to hardware. This differences are especially noticeable between older Intel- and newer Apple Silicon-based machines.

I'm using `VTCopySupportedPropertyDictionaryForEncoder` to explicitly sanitize the properties and filter out the ones that are not supported on a particular hardware. `AVVideoQualityKey` is pretty much always comes out as supported. However, in rare cases I get an exception when creating `AVAssetWriterInput` when it's supported – which is the weird part.

As a last resort, I've added an Objective-C exception handler, which feels like a very bad hack-around. It gets the job done, but it would be great to learn if anyone knows a better way of handling this or has some tips or other insights?